# Xcode 7 Beta WON'T INSTALL

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, beta, xcode7

I've been trying to install the Xcode 7 Beta 3 from Apple for hours and it just won't run on Yosemite 10.10.3. I download and run the installer, and everything works fine, but when I try to open Xcode beta I get a window that lasts for 30 minutes that says "Verifying" and then when it closes sometimes I get a window that says the Xcode beta was downloaded from the internet and it wants to know if I still want to open it. I click "Open" and nothing happens!!! According to task manager, Xcode beta is not responding. I've tried to reverify it 6 times, and even deleted and reinstalled xcode 7 beta from Apple. I'm going to put the El Capitan public beta on my external hard drive and see if xcode 7 will run on that. Though, is there anyway I can get Xcode 7 Beta 3 to run on Yosemite 10.10.3? I have a mid-2009 MacBook Pro, 2.66GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4 GB RAM, 256GB SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason when I added the the xcode beta to my external drive, I opened the one in my external hard drive and now it works just fine. Maybe there's a bug that makes sure that there can't be two versions of Xcode on the same drive?

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same issue with Xcode 7 beta 4. According [to this blog post](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/9/8/xcode-6-beta-is-slow-to-open-fix-gate-keeper-slowness-with-the-terminal) you just need to quarantine it to disable the Gate Keeper check.

```
cd /Applications
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode-beta.app
open Xcode-beta.app
```

assuming your install folder is /Applications

**Update:**

This command may not fix everything that needs to disable Gate Keeper. For maximum efficiency, use the recursive flag to make sure to get everything (including simulators) packaged in the app.

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine Xcode-beta.app
```

Note: you need sudo since some of the files are protected.

Answer (score 0):

I have both XCode 6.4 ans XCode 7 installed on the internal drive of my macbook OSX 10.10.3 and it works...

Comment: The strangest part was after I opened it on the external, Xcode 7 on my internal drive worked. I haven't had any trouble with it since.